# Is there a vb.net equivalent of C++11 std::async?

Tags: vb.net

While doing some stuff in c++ recently, I learned about async and just found it to be incredibly convenient:

```
future<int> somefuture = async(somefunc);

... 

int result = somefuture.get();
```

I've done async processing by creating threading.thread in vb.net before but is there anything like async that I can use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [`Task` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task) and the [`Await` keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx).

For more information, see my [blog post](http://blog.slaks.net/2014-12-23/parallelism-async-threading-explained/).